# IIS Managed -> Unmanaged -> Managed -> StackOverflowException

Tags: .net, iis, pinvoke, stack-overflow, unmanaged

I'll try to describe my problem as detailed as possible, but if more detailed explanation is needed, please let me know.

To simplify let say I have 3 DLLs (actually I have more, but it is not very important, I guess):

1. `managed-1.dll` - Managed DLL (writen in C# .NET 4.0)  - handles requests and during some requests invokes unmanaged code in second DLL
2. `unmanaged.dll` - Unmanaged DLL (writen in old school VC++ 6.0) - performs several operations and sometimes calls the third DLL
3. `managed-2.dll` - Managed DLL (writen in CLI/C++ .NET 3.5) - the root of my problem

I run my code in 3 different scenarios:

1. I call `managed-1.dll` from console application - everything works well
2. I call `managed-1.dll` from `ASP.NET Development Server` - everything works well too
3. I call `managed-1.dll` from `IIS` - everything works well until whole sequence `managed-1.dll -> unmanaged.dll -> managed-2.dll` is involved.

In scenario 3 the StackOverflowException is thrown. The debugger shows that no recursion is involved. Also it is clear that the exception is occured in the following type of call stack:

- `managed-1.dll::CallUnmanagedCode()`
- `unmanaged.dll::SomeMethod1()`
- `unmanaged.dll::SomeMethod2()`
- `unmanaged.dll::CallManagedCode()`
- `managed-2.dll::CallUnmanagedCode()` **!! marked with `__declspec(dllexport)` and does not use any managed types !!**
- `managed-2.dll::FailingMethod()` **!! uses managed types; in a very beginning (even the first line of code is not performed) an exception is occured !!**

The one more interesting thing: the debugger shows not the same parameter values in the `FailingMethod` as compared to the values in the method calling point.

If somebody has any clue, please advice.

**Solution:** The problem was not related to the managed-unmanaged stuff, but to the [IIS stack size](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/03/31/stack-sizes-in-iis-affects-asp-net.aspx). For me the usage of the [editbin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xd3shwhf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) tool was not acceptable solution. So my solution - to create new thread before call of the `unmanaged.dll` and set stack to 1 MB:

```
var result = unchecked ((int)0x800000FF);
var thread = new Thread(() => { result = pinvoke_func(); }, 1024 * 1024); // 1MB
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
```

Comment: Link to effectively duplicate (but older) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319711/increase-stack-size-iis-asp-net-3-5 - also covers both the microsoft article and the explicit-thread-creation workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stack size for normal windows applications is apparently 1MB, but for IIS it is 256KB (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932909). This would perhaps explain why the application behaves in the console application but not in IIS.

I don't know exactly what the stack size is for the ASP.NET development server but it's probably 1MB, see this SO question for more information: [stackoverflowexception-in-iis7-but-not-in-cassini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013037/stackoverflowexception-in-iis7-but-not-in-cassini)

Apparently it's possible to increase the stack size for IIS using editbin.
See this article for instructions: [Stack sizes in IIS - affects ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20160316195628/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/03/31/stack-sizes-in-iis-affects-asp-net.aspx)

Comment: thanx for the tip! I'll guess this could be the root of my problem. I'll try to increase stacksize and let you know the results